# Installation issue with Python3.8, pip, and distutils

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, python, pip

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 system from `python3.7` to `python3.8`. I now want to install a `python3.8` package. So, I ran: `python3.8 -m pip install xyz`, where `xyz` is the package name (for example, I have tried `torch`, `numpy`, and `opencv-python` for the package name, and all three packages give the same result). However, this gave the following error messages:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)
```

So, I took a look at the content of `/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils`. Indeed, there is no module named `sysconfig`. In fact, there are only two files: `__init__.py` and `version.py`. However, when I look at the same for `python3.7` in `/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils`, I can then see the module `sysconfig`.

I then tried to reinstall `dstutils` for `python3.8`, by running: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils`. However, this gave me the following error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-distutils'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-distutils'
```

So now, I am really stuck! I seem to need `distutils` to install any packages, but my installation of `distutils` seems to be incomplete. And yet, I cannot seem to install `distutils` using `apt get`.

Please can somebody help?

Comment: Historically it has been problematic to tinker with the python installations in Ubuntu, this due to the fact that e.g. `apt` and `apt-get` might get affected, for starters.

Comment: Yes, I haven't been able to solve this, and will probably do an OS reinstall. Next time I will just stick to using a virtual environment!

Comment: So, it appears the problems persist. "Reinstall" seems to be the easy way out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Answer:

The Ubuntu package manager, i.e. `apt` or `apt-get` is heavily dependent on a working python; so heavily that it isn't easy to replace or update the python installation.

Also note: As of 20.04, there is no installed python2 in Ubuntu.

Any problems similar to the above; the easy way out is a reinstall.