# do-release-upgrade broke python's virtual environment and pip

Tags: upgrade, python, virtualenvwrapper

I did a release upgrade, followed by `apt upgrade` no problem, everything went smooth. Except, now virtual environments don't work at all. I have various one set up for various django projects I'm working on. When I try to run `django manage.py runserver` I get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

OK, weird, so I'll try to install django again

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

And I cannot run `pip` outside the virtual environment, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-manag/75696359#75696359).

So what is the practice now? Do I need to recreate my virtual environments?

Update:
If I create a new environment (`mkvirtualenv new_env`) pip works fine.

Edit:
Sorry, I forgot to add. I've updated from mainstream Ubuntu 22.10 to mainstream Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Upgrade from what to what?

Comment: Sorry, I took that for granted, and I shouldn't have. I've updated from mainstream Ubuntu 23.10 to mainstream Ubuntu 23.04

I added that to my question.

Comment: You might need to run `pip3 install -U django` ... etc. ... Please see for example:  [python3.8 and pip after upgrading to 22.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1456669)

Comment: 23.10 does not even exist yet. Will not be out till Oct. that makes this off topic.

Comment: Sorry... it is Ubuntu 22.10, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried @Raffa's solution but then I see that `pip` is not installed. Following that hint I found in another thread how to fix that:

> python -m ensurepip --default-pip

After that I needed to install the packages again though.