# Encountering "Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault" error in python script

Tags: 22.04, python3, segmentation-fault

Recently my system got upgraded from ubuntu18.04.1 to ubuntu22.04.2 and as a result of which the following got upgraded as below:
python 3.7.5 to python3.10.6
Mysql 5.7.38 to mysql 8.0.31

I see, segmentation faults occurring in irregular intervals with no repeated stack traces.
The issue was not seen prior to upgrade and no code changes have been made during and after upgrade.
None of default setting/configurations have been modified.
I am using pymysql(1.0.2) to connect to Mysql.

1. Does ubuntu22.04.2 version along with above upgrades consume additional memory space, if so any suggestions on how much this could be approximately?
2. Are any default system configurations modified from ubuntu18.04.1 to ubuntu22.04.2, that needs to be changed?
3. Are there any known defects from this upgarde that can be pointed to (python modules associated with python3.10.6 etc)?
4. Does python3.10.6 has any memory limitations, if so where to check those values?

Comment: You might need to update your installed modules with `pip3 install -U ...` ... Please see for example [python3.8 and pip after upgrading to 22.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1456669)

Comment: AFAIK a *segmentation fault* is not related to the amount of memory consumed - it's about a program accessing memory that was not allocated to it (due, for example, to a pointer programming error)