# Ubuntu 22.04 can't resume from suspend but reboots instead

Tags: 22.04, suspend, reboot

After a recent update, I noticed my Ubuntu 22.04 system doesn't seem to be able to resume from suspend mode. Instead, it reboots/restarts the OS. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1478137/968501